# AS3 - Change MovieClip-Color Using Filters

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I wonder how I can create an "Adjust Color"-filter in AS3.

I created a red box in Photoshop (8x8px), saved it as a PNG-file, then I imported it to Flash. I converted the file to a MovieClip-symbol. I applied an "Adjust Color"-filter. With that I can change the color easily, but I want to get the same effect in AS3.

Does anyone have a clue on how?
Thanks:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change MovieClip color use `ColorTransform` class and `transform.colortransform` property of the `MovieClip`:

```
var ct:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
ct.color = 0xCFFF54;
yourMovieClip.transform.colorTransform = ct;
```

---

**Advanced method**

Using this method you can change brightness, contrast, etc.

```
import fl.motion.AdjustColor;

var adjustColor:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor();
adjustColor.brightness = 50;
adjustColor.contrast = 50;
adjustColor.saturation = 50;
adjustColor.hue = 50;

var matrix:Array = adjustColor.CalculateFinalFlatArray();
var colorMatrix:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter(matrix);

yourMovieClip.filters = [colorMatrix];
```